# Inability to Toggle a Sidebar Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I've all my CSS and Javascript inside my HTML file on Django which looks as follows:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <script>
          function toggleSidebar(){
              document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
          }
      </script>


      <style type="text/css">

          .toggle-btn {
              position:absolute;
              left:180px;
              top:70px
          }

          .toggle-btn span {
              display:block;
              width:30px;
              height:5px;
              background:#000000;
              margin: 5px 0px;
          }

          .sidebar {
              height:100%;
              width:160px;
              position: fixed;
              z-index:1;
              top:0;
              let:0;
              background-color:#111;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              padding-top:70px;                                                  
          }

          .sidebar.active {
              left:0px
          }

          .sidebar a {
              padding:6px 8px 6px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size:18px;
              color: #818181;
              display:block;

          }

           .sidebar a:hover {
               color:#ffffff;

          }

      </style>

  </head>


  <body>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <div class="toggle-btn">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar">


          <a href="/categories">Categories</a>
          <a href="#">Test 1</a>
          <a href="#">Test 2</a>
          <a href="#">Test 3</a>
          <a href="#">Test 4</a>

      </div>


  </body>


<header class="site-header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
    <div class="container">


      <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="#">Home.com</a>


      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<section class="hero">
            <div class="hero-inner">
                <h1>Centered Text</h1>

            </div>
        </section>



</header>

</body>    
</html>
```

I wanted to toggle the sidebar, that means triggering a hide function when someone clicks on the hamburger menu indicated by the `spann` tag, as you can probably tell by the following:

```
<script>
      function toggleSidebar(){
          document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
      }
  </script>
```

So far it's not working yet as excepted, given that I'm an absolute beginner to CSS & Javascript. I would be super appreciative if someone could point out the things I might have done wrong.

In [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodingAddict/pen/WNvKLVJ)

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the toggle functionality, hope this helps:

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0];

  if(x.classList.contains('active')) {
    x.classList.remove('active')
    return;
  }

  x.classList.add('active')
}
```

if you check the sidebar div you'll see that class is being added and removed on toogle

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method. You need to have an onclick event on your .toggle-button with the name of your method (toggleSidebar), so it knows to call it when it's clicked. 
You can also add an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to your button instead of onclick.

```css
.toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  top: 70px;
}

.toggle-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    function toggleSidebar() {
      $(".sidebar").toggle();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="/categories">Categories</a>
    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
    <a href="#">Test 3</a>
    <a href="#">Test 4</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why does the hamburger stay at it's place and not move along to the side ?

Comment: The toggleSideBar() is only toggling the sidebar. One way to move the hamburger is to change the left positioning. You can keep a count variable, and increase or decrease the left positioning based on count. You can use jQuery's css(), or just use style in JS. Hope that helps.

Comment: I would suggest you spend some time on it before asking others for help. Stack Overflow is not meant for others to do your code. You can then edit this question with the new issue you are having and the things you have tried or ask a new question.

Comment: I have tried many things, including your code, and so far nothing has proven to work.